# multiselect with first element selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have created multiselect for a id multiselect.I want to choose the first item as chosen .

```
    <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="project_list" class="jqmsLoaded ms-list-1" style="display: none;">
<option value="Blue QA">Blue QA</option>
<option value="Easybridge">Easybridge</option>
<option value="K12RS">K12RS</option><option value="LEM">LEM</option>

</select>

 $('#multiselect').multiselect({
        search:true,
        selectAll: true,
        //select : [0], //
        texts: {
          search: 'Search Projects',
           placeholder: 'Select Projects',
      },
      });
```

I want to select Blue QA as selected on load.
THe options are loaded dynamically.

tried to added as `$('#multiselect select option:first-child').prop("selected", true);`
but no luck

Comment: where to add it

Comment: Write in your jquery `var o1= $('#multiselect').multiselect("widget"); o1.find(":checkbox").first().click();`

Comment: tried but no luck

Comment: can you pleas share your complete code

Answer (score 0):

You need to call multi-select you can select the option of multi select by calling its option again.

```js
$('#multiselect').multiselect({
        search:true,
        selectAll: true,
        texts: {
          search: 'Search Projects',
           placeholder: 'Select Projects',
        },
      });
      
      var select_1 =  $('#multiselect option:eq(0)').val();
      //selecting element of multiiselect
      $('#multiselect').multiselect('select', select_1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha256-qoj3D1oB1r2TAdqKTYuWObh01rIVC1Gmw9vWp1+q5xw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple multiselect" name="project_list" class="jqmsLoaded ms-list-1" style="display: none;">
<option  value="Blue QA">Blue QA</option>
<option value="Easybridge">Easybridge</option>
<option value="K12RS">K12RS</option><option value="LEM">LEM</option>

</select>
```

Comment: not a big deal you just need to pass dynamic variable like that       
for example var select_ele = "what ever your element is comning and what it is" $('#multiselect').multiselect('select', select_ele );

Comment: tried but no luck even with hardcoded value any clue

Comment: check now you just need to get the first option whatever it is will be selected like that

Comment: var select_1 =  $('#multiselect option:eq(0)').val();
  
      $('#multiselect').multiselect('select', select_1);

Answer (score 0):

Jus add this script on load as shown below:-

```
$(function(){

$('#multiselect').multiselect('select', $("#multiselect option:first").val()); 

//second approach 

$("#multiselect").val($("#multiselect option:first").val());
$('#multiselect').multiselect('rebuild');    //important to rebuild if any changes done using script



})
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/70Ldt9xa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#multiselect").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
});
```

This should work as this sets the selected index. In `prop()` function first parameter is passed to select an index, and the second parameter which is set to `0` now, is to specify which `<option>` you want to be selected. So you can pass any existing index number in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#multiselect select option:first-child').prop("selected", true);
 $('#multiselect').multiselect('refresh');
});
```